# Acoustic foam orientation effectiveness when mounting directly to a furnace

Tags: sound-design

I have a home office in the corner of my unfinished basement. About 20 feet away is my furnace that has a fan on 24/7. I would to like reduce the sound of from air movement and the blower with some wedged acoustic foam. From my office chair, I can only see the back side of the furnace. All of the items that shouldn't be covered up (i.e access panels, vents, etc) are on the other side.

I thinking of mounting the foam directly on the outside of the furnace with the wedges facing out. Will this orientation of the foam significantly reduce its effectiveness?

Also, walling off the furnace is not an option I can take.

Answer (score 1):

Acoustic foam is not very heat resistant. In most cases there are inflammable goods. So do not mount the against the furnace. One thing that you could do is using whit board like panels to mount the acoustic foam. (Be sure to use thick heavy foam, as normal foam just reduces very high frequencies) Then you have free standing panels that yo ucan place everywhere and with enough distance to the furnace.

Answer (score 1):

Look for acoustic insulation materials for boats or vehicles. They are usually heat resistant.
Regular wedge foam on the furnace won't help much. However, what you could do is cover the wall opposite the access panels and vents with a dampening material, because that is where the sound coming out of the furnace reflects towards you.